# Meaning of "Smile Awryls"

Tags: meaning

My cousin owns an old joke book, of dubious quality, called "Super Jokes and Riddles". It is divided into several catchily-titled sections, mostly based on the subject matter of the jokes (e.g., "Say Ah! Ah! Ah!" for jokes about doctors/medicine; "Silly Dillies" for jokes about pickles [of which there are actually surprisingly many]).

However, one of the sections has a title I can't make sense of. It is called "Smile Awryls". My cousin asked me what "awryls" were and I had no idea; I looked this (presumably plural) word up later and failed to find it in any dictionaries. A Google search for "smile awryls" turns up only one result, which seems to be an eBay review for the aforementioned joke book.

Based on the fact that many of these sections have rhyming or near-rhyming names, I'd say "awryls" is most likely intended to be pronounced uh-RYE-ulz. Also, unlike many other sections, there was no real theme to the jokes in this section, making me guess that a "Smile Awryl" was just a generic name for a joke, something that stirs up a smile among its readers. The word is similar to "awry", but I'm not sure I can find any connection between the two.

Has anyone seen or heard of this word/two-word phrase anywhere else before? Or, better yet, does anyone here own a copy of this joke book (or remember having owned it) and have their own interpretation of the word? Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: It strikes me as, if anything, a misprint or miscopy of _always_.

Comment: I think you're right that it's a way to make *awry* rhyme with *smile*. Can you describe the jokes that fall under "Smile Awryls"? Does something seem wrong / unconventional about them? I picture jokes like [No soap radio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_soap_radio) or other [anti-humor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-humor) jokes going under that section.

Comment: Actually, I managed to find the book and look over the jokes in that section again. The humour in them was, indeed, a little "darker" than average. I guess I can see where they were coming from with the "wry" element of the title. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me, it looks like Smile Awhiles (plural) combined with wry, as in wry sense of humor.

Comment: Yeah, I reckon it was just a bad attempt at combining "awhile" with "wry".